# difference between sizes javascript transform:scale(?.?)

Tags: javascript, css, math, percentage

using javascript to calculate; how do I use transform:scale(w,h); to get this div to scale to fit its parent container?

I was in special math group at school so I'm not sure what I am googling (ratio, length comparison, proportion, fraction?) seen as we never learned that stuff (maybe for a day or two).

```
<div id="container"style="width:164px;height:164px:">

    <div id="square_of_unknown_size"> I want to always fill my parent </div>

</div>
```

edit: btw, I don't want to use width/height:100% because I have an image inside the square that is fit like that so, i really need to zoom.

this seems to zoom inward to the microscopic level:

```
'-webkit-transform':'scale('+$('#container').width()+'.'+$('#square_of_unknown_size').width()+','+$('#container').height()+'.'+$('#square_of_unknown_size').height()+')'
```

px A compare B px get A.B = always fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the proportion between the two divs:

```
var scaleX = $('#container').width() / $('#square_of_unknown_size').width();
var scaleY = $('#container').height() / $('#square_of_unknown_size').height();
$('#square_of_unknown_size').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')');
```

Comment: I cant see how its just divide!? and cause my div is always a square shape its like scale(scale+','+scale)

Comment: can the effect be reversed?

Comment: For example, if the container is 200x200, and the content is 100x100, the scale is 2.0, i.e., the content must be scaled by a factor of 2 to fit the container.